# Load variable from JSON file to Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON that is downloaded from Google BigQuery and has only one value. How do I get this variable to be represented in my Python Script. Thank you for the help!

```
import smtplib
import os

from slacker import Slacker

def post_slack():
    """Post slack message."""
    try:
        slack = Slacker(token)

        obj = slack.chat.post_message(
            channel='#dataworksapp',
            as_user=True,
            attachments=[
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
            "color": "#36a64f",
            "pretext": "Optional text that appears above the attachment block",
            "author_name": "Data Works",
            "author_link": "http://flickr.com/bobby/",
            "author_icon": "http://flickr.com/icons/bobby.jpg",
            "title": "BlueBox Weekly Information",
            "title_link": "https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/firebase_results/?project=dataworks-356fa",
            "text": "Optional text that appears within the attachment",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "BlueBox Devices Connected",
                    "value": "High",
                    "short": 'true'
                },
                {
                    "title": "BlueBox Connection Time",
                    "value": "High",
                    "short": 'true'
                }
            ],
            "image_url": "http://my-website.com/path/to/image.jpg",
            "thumb_url": "http://example.com/path/to/thumb.png",
            "footer": "Slack API",
            "footer_icon": "https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/default_application_icon.png",
            "ts": 123456789
        }])
        print obj.successful, obj.__dict__['body']['channel'], obj.__dict__[
            'body']['ts']
    except KeyError, ex:
        print 'Environment variable %s not set.' % str(ex)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    post_slack()
```

This is the code I have. I would need the "value" part in the attachments to be the variable uploaded from JSON.

Comment: Please post some code so we can help you!

Comment: I have added my code in an edit. Thank you

Comment: handling json data is well documented, and there are countless examples on the internet. What research have you done before asking? See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: I have loaded a JSON successfully before but is that the same as loading a value from JSON and saving this value as a variable to use else where in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
json_text = '{"some":"json"}'
some_dict = json.loads(json_text)
```